# check if element has something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, I receive a row of data from JSON and print the data on the HTML like

```
<p id="checker">1+2</p>
```

and below i have some checkboxes

```
<p style="display:none" id="1">cat</p>
<p style="display:none" id="2">dog</p>
<p style="display:none" id="3">fish</p>
```

And I'd like to make some p tags appear if the if statement is true

```
if ($("#checker").html() == "1") {
  $("#1").css("display", "block");
}

elseif($("#checker").html() == "2") {
  $("#2").css("display", "block");
}
```

but I realized that this can't satisfy my need.
Is there another solution for this task?

Comment: I'd like to know can do something similar with if hasClass()

Comment: better still, use .text() instead of .html()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split the string and iterate over them, based on the value get element and show.

```js
$('#checker')
  .html() // get html content
  .split('+') // split string by +
  .forEach(function(v) { // iterate over them
    $('#' + $.trim(v)).show() // get element by id and show
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="checker">1+2</p>
<p style="display:none" id="1">cat</p>
<p style="display:none" id="2">dog</p>
<p style="display:none" id="3">fish</p>
```

Comment: This is prefect. Thanks, this is just very advance but simple.

Comment: @anson920520 : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the jQuery `show()` function, like so:

```
if($("#checker").html()=="1"){
    $("#1").show();
}
elseif($("#checker").html()=="2"){
    $("#2").show();
}
```

If you need to hide them again, you can use the `hide()` function the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Have something does not mean `==`. You can use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) to check if a string has something or not.

Try this

```
if($("#checker").html().indexOf("1")!=-1){
        $("#1").css("display","block");
     }
```